# Adding data from array to html table in Java

Tags: java, html, android-webview

I am trying to add images in a webview for each 3 column but the image are displayed outside the table in horizontal. where am i wrong ? a hint please.

```
        String str = "";           
        str += "<table width='200' border='1'><tr>";
        int i = 1;

        for (i=1; i < my_image.length-1; i++) {
            if (i%3==0) {    
                str += "<td><a href='"+my_image[i]+"'"+" class='popup-open'><img src='"+my_image[i]+""+"width='80' height='65'></a></td></tr><tr>";
            } else {
                str+= "<td><a href='"+my_image[i]+"'class='popup-open'><img src=' "+my_image[i]+"' width='80' height='65'></a></td></tr>";    
            }
            str+="</tr></table>";
        }

        html_content = "<strong>"+title+"</strong>" +
                " <br><br><img src='"+single_image+"'width='300' height='211'>" +    
                "<br> " +   
                ""+content+"<br>"+str;
```

Comment: is your html well formed? You've the closing tags for `tr` and `table` within the `for` loop.

Comment: Don't mix HTML and Java code. Move your Java code to Java beans (or Servlets) and avoid this hateful string concatenation (or scriplets, if you're planning).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost certainly you aren't closing a tag somewhere every opening HTML tag should be closed.

You are definitely ending your table with `<tr></tr>` which is not very nice.

***You should definitely do some research into using JSP or similar.  Using JSTL within your JSPs would be much preferable, easier to read and more maintainable in the long run.  An hour's reading of a JSTL / JSP tutorial would save you many in the future.***

EDIT:
Actually it looks like you aren't closing the `'` around the src attribute:

`str += "<td><a href='"+my_image[i]+"'"+" class='popup-open'><img 
src='"+my_image[i]+""+`

should be:

`str += "<td><a href='"+my_image[i]+"'"+" class='popup-open'><img 
src='"+my_image[i]+"'"+`

Also using width and height attributes is bad form. Set a class using the class attribute and size the images with CSS - it will prevent headaches / code changes if you want to change the size of the images at any point in the future.

Comment: sorry but i don't understand

Comment: See my edit, it should explain your problem...

Comment: solved :) thanks you. though the table border is invisible

Comment: Table border should be set using css.  Put a class on your table and style it using the collowing css: `table.my_table_class { border: 1px solid black }` or however you want it styled...

Answer (score 2):

As it has already been stated you are probably missing a closing tag or an apostrophe somewhere.

Actually generating HTML code by a concatenation of `String`s is not really a good idea. I would recommend you to check this [Jackarta ECS](http://jakarta.apache.org/ecs/index.html) library for HTML generation. It takes care of all the technical moments and claims to be HTML 4.0 compatible, though it is no longer supported.

Otherwise you could check this [JATL](http://code.google.com/p/jatl/) project or the HTMLEditorKit from [javax.swing.text.html](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/html/package-summary.html)